# Getting the offset of a variable inside a struct is based on the NULL pointer, but why?

Tags: c

I found a trick on a youtube video explaining how you can get the offset of a struct member by using a NULL pointer. I understand the code snippit below (the casts, the ampersand, and so on), but I do not understand why this works with the NULL pointer. I thought that the NULL pointer could not point to anything. So I cannot mentally visualize how it works. Second, the NULL pointer is not always represented by the compiler as being 0, somtimes it is a non-zero value. But than how could this piece of code work correctly ? Or wouldn't it work correctly anymore ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    /* Getting the offset of a variable inside a struct */
    typedef struct {
        int a;
        char b[23];
        float c;
    } MyStructType;

    unsigned offset = (unsigned)(&((MyStructType * )NULL)->c);

    printf("offset = %u\n", offset);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With `&` you're getting the address and not the pointed value.

Comment: Is your code behaving as expected ? Are you only looking for an explanation or a solution ? please rephrase your question

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is undefined behaviour (dereferencing a NULL pointer). Use [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof)

Comment: nabil.douss the code is working, the offset is 28, but I'm wondering why it works with the NULL pointer ?

Comment: Well, in C as there are no multiple inheritance and v-table, this would usually work when NULL is defined to be address 0 if the actual instruction does not validate the address.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I found a trick on a youtube video explaining how you can get the
>   offset of a struct member by using a NULL pointer.

Well, at least you came here to ask about the random Internet advice you turned up.  We're an Internet resource ourselves, of course, but I like to think that our structure and reputation gives you a basis for estimating the reliability of what we have to say.

> I understand the
>   code snippit below (the casts, the ampersand, and so on), but I do not
>   understand why this works with the NULL pointer. I thought that the
>   NULL pointer could not point to anything.

Yes, from the perspective of C semantics, a null pointer *definitely* does not point to anything, and `NULL` is a null pointer constant.

> So I cannot mentally
>   visualize how it works.

The (flawed) idea is that

- `NULL` is equivalent to a pointer to address 0 in a flat address space (**unsafe assumption**);
- `((MyStructType * )NULL)->c` designates the member `c` of an altogether hypothetical object of type `MyStructType` residing at that address (**not supported by the standard**);
- applying the `&` operator yields the address that such a member *would* have if it in fact existed (**not supported by the standard**); and
- converting the resulting address to an integer yields an address in the assumed flat address space, expressed in units the size of a C `char` (**in no way guaranteed**);
- so that the resulting integer simultaneously represents both an absolute address and an offset (follows from the previous assumptions, because the supposed base address of the hypothetical structure is 0).

> Second, the NULL pointer is not always
>   represented by the compiler as being 0, somtimes it is a non-zero
>   value.

Quite right, that is one of the flaws in the scheme presented.

> But than how could this piece of code work correctly ? Or
>   wouldn't it work correctly anymore ?

Although the Standard provides no basis to justify relying on the code to behave as advertised, that does not mean that it must necessarily fail.  C implementations do need to be internally consistent about how they represent null pointers, and -- to a certain degree -- about how they convert between pointers and integer.  It turns out to be fairly common that the code's assumptions about those things are in fact satisfied by implementations.

So in practice, the code does work with many C implementations.  But it systematically produces the wrong answer with some others, and there may be some in which it produces the right answer some appreciable fraction of the time, but the wrong answer the rest of the time.

Answer (score 8):

This code is platform specific. This code might cause undefined behaviour on one platform and it might work on others.
That's why the C standard requires every library to implement the offsetof macro which could expand to code like derefering the NULL pointer, at least you can be sure the code will not crash on any platform

```
typedef struct Struct
{
  double d;
} Struct;

offsetof(Struct, d)
```

Answer (score 8):

Note that this code is actually **undefined behaviour**. Dereferencing a NULL pointer is never allowed, even if no value is accessed, only the address (this was a root cause for a [linux kernel exploit](https://lwn.net/Articles/342330/))

Use [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof) instead for a save alternative.

---

As to why it seems works with a NULL pointer: it assumes that NULL is 0. Basically you could use any pointer and calculate:

```
MyStructType t; 
unsigned off = (unsigned)(&(&t)->c) - (unsigned)&t;
```

if `&t == 0`, this becomes:

```
 unsigned off = (unsigned)(&(0)->c) - 0;
```

Substracting 0 is a no-op

Comment: There is no de-referencing anywhere. It's a dirty hack but not for that reason, but rather because null pointers aren't necessarily zero.

Comment: I'm not so sure, @Lundin. The `->` sub-expression produces an lvalue designating a member of a structure that definitely does not exist, which can plausibly be characterized as a dereference even if that lvalue is not used to access the object to which it refers.  The problem here is that the standard does not describe the relevant constraints and semantics in terms of "dereferencing".

Comment: I was wrong about the citation, that exploit was a clearly dereferencing a null... but there is  a debate if this counts as dereferencing a null pointer. see https://www.viva64.com/en/b/0306/

Comment: @JohnBollinger Hmm perhaps you are correct, the `.` and `->` operators are described as "The value is that of the named member, and is an lvalue if the first expression is an lvalue." Sounds very much like a potential value access.

Comment: The statement “Dereferencing a NULL pointer is never allowed” is not correct. By and large, the C standard does not specify what is allowed or not allowed. It specifies, or does not specify, what happens if a program does various things. In regard to dereferencing a null pointer, it does not say it is not allowed—the C standard merely says that the C standard does not define the behavior. This means that the operation **may** be allowed by a C implementation, and it may even be defined by a C implementation. (Nonetheless, `offset` is the preferred technique.)

Answer (score 2):

This is a dirty hack and might not necessarily work.

`(MyStructType * )NULL` creates a null pointer. *Null pointer* and *null pointer constant* are two different terms. `NULL` is guaranteed to be a *null pointer constant* equivalent to 0, but the obtained null pointer we get when casting it to another type can be any implementation-defined value.

So it happened to work by luck on your specific system, you could as well have gotten any strange value.

The `offsetof` macro has been standard C since 1989 so maybe your Youtube hacker is still stuck in the early 1980s.

Comment: `NULL` is not necessarily equivalent to 0

Comment: @palapapa ISO C17 6.5.9. It is guaranteed to _compare_ equal to `0`. Or rather when you do `NULL == 0` each operand is converted to a null pointer and two null pointers always compare equal. Or in case `NULL` is defined as `0`, then `0 == 0` compares equal too.

Answer (score 2):

This question resembles me to something seen more than 30 years ago:

```
#define XtOffset(p_type,field) \
    ((Cardinal) (((char *) (&(((p_type)NULL)->field))) - ((char *) NULL)))

#ifdef offsetof
#define XtOffsetOf(s_type,field) offsetof(s_type,field)
#else
#define XtOffsetOf(s_type,field) XtOffset(s_type*,field)
#endif
```

from  xorg-libXt/include/X11/Intrinsic.h X11R4. 
They took into account that a NULL Pointer could be different to 0x0 and included that in the definition of the XtOffsetOf macro.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question so that it does not sound offensive to anybody without your expertise.